# In RStudio, scale_fill_brewer() creates grey bars as default bar graph, not a range of blues

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm attempting to color a bar plot with `scale_fill_brewer()` using the `Vocab` dataset from the package `car` in RStudio.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(car)
library(RColorBrewer)

# An ordinal dataset
ggplot(Vocab, aes(x = education, fill = vocabulary)) +
 geom_bar(position = "fill") +
 # Use the default brewed color palette
 scale_fill_brewer()
```

Using the an online R session via DataCamp, I am able to generate this:
[default RColorBrewer palette is "Blues"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/759Bi.png)

Since the default `RColorBrewer` palette that `scale_fill_brewer()` calls is "Blues," I expect to see the above plot generated on my desktop. However, when I transfer the above code to RStudio on Windows 10, `ggplot2` generates this: [grey bars instead of blue gradation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8H1S.png)

I attempted to correct the plot by:
    # Definition of a set of blue colors from RColorBrewer package
    blues <- brewer.pal(9, "Blues")

```
# Make a color range using colorRampPalette()
blue_range <- colorRampPalette(blues)

# Use blue_range to adjust the color of the bars
ggplot(Vocab, aes(x = education, fill = vocabulary)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = blue_range(11))
```

This block of code should generate a bar plot [that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/170hF.png). But, it doesn't. All of the bars are still grey.

I don't understand why this code works on the online R session but not in my own personal RStudio session. Help?

Comment: `Vocab$vocabulary` is numeric, but you're trying to use a discrete fill scale, which only works for factors. Run `Vocab$vocabulary <- factor(Vocab$vocabulary)` before plotting, then your color scales should show up fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `fill = factor(vocabulary)`

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(car)
library(RColorBrewer)

blues <- brewer.pal(9, "Blues")
blue_range <- colorRampPalette(blues)

ggplot(Vocab, aes(x = education, fill = factor(vocabulary))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = blue_range(11))
```

[image]